# Alarm firing too often

Tags: android

Had code working properly with a `WakeFulBroadcast` receiver previously and based this off of that. Just trying to set an alarm that runs a service every day at that same time, and will restart if the device is restarted.

Instead, it's running roughly every 30-50 minutes, seemingly randomly.

**MyReceiver.java**

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
        scheduleAlarms(context);
    }       
}

static void scheduleAlarms(Context context) {

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);

    PendingIntent scheduledIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    if (am != null) {
        am.cancel(scheduledIntent);
    }

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

    // if it's after or equal to desired time, then schedule for the next day

   // also tried:
   // if (Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) >= 8) {

    if (calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) >= 8) {
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1); // add, not set!
    } else {
        //Alarm will schedule for today
    }

    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, scheduledIntent);

}
```

**MyService.java**

```
 @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        sendNotification(getApplicationContext());
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // SharedPreferences boolean that I've omitted
        if (!runOnce) {
            Log.d("main activity", "First time running app");
            editor.putBoolean(RUN_ONCE, true);
            editor.commit();

            MyReceiver.scheduleAlarms(getApplicationContext());

        }

}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

.
.
.

```
   <receiver
        android:name=".MyReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
        </intent-filter>

    </receiver>
```